# Eclipse | Selection does not contain a main type yet main is there

Tags: java, eclipse

There are other answers on this, but none of them provided me with a solution.

Common solutions seem to be that the code is not within the "src" Source Folder and that the main method exists.

I've also done a Project > Clean and I've been to Run > Run Configurations... but nothing appeared when searching for the "Main" class.

**My Code**

```
package com.TobyMellor.TrainRouteFinder;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // testing
    }

    // other classes
}
```

[image]

Comment: you have Errors in your Project. Maybe the class is not compiled yet

Comment: how are you running that application??

Comment: @Jens Sorry I modified the App.java for simplification for this post. Let me edit it one second

Comment: @Jens Edited the image

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ What do you mean? I'm clicking on "Run > Run" in the Toolbar at the top

Comment: @TobyMellor There is no picrue visible

Comment: @Jens It's showing for me, but here's an imgur link http://imgur.com/a/ol1We

Comment: Can you do a "Project"-->"Clean..." ?

Comment: @Jens Yes I've just done that again, clicking "Project > Clean..." then "Clean all projects" then "OK". Then clicking on App.java, then hitting run again gives the same error

Comment: If you click into the Editor window then right click run as ... what is Happening than?

Comment: @Jens Similar error. Clicking into App.java in the text section, Run > Run As > Java Application gives "Editor does not contain a main type." http://imgur.com/a/cakDq

Comment: Very strange. My only guess is that the classes are not compiled by any reason

Comment: @Jens How would you do that? All I've done is create a new project, created packages in src, created class files and pasted in the code I made in IntelliJ IDEA

Comment: Is "Build automatically" in menu "Project" activated?

Comment: @Jens Yes, it's got a tick on the left of it. Disabling it then cleaning shows the same error, as does re-enabling it then cleaning it still shows the error.

Comment: @Jens I tried renaming my project from "TrainRouteFinder | Eclipse" to "TrainRouteFinder Eclipse", restarted eclipse and reopened the new project and it's working now. Strange. Thanks for the help!

Comment: EHC you have the ide Name in project name?

Comment: @Jens I'm submitting coursework, I've been using IntelliJ but I believe the lecturer uses Eclipse. I wanted to make sure it's working in Eclipse too so I'm submitting both as well as a JAR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encountered this myself a few days ago. Try changing the String[] to String... in the main Method declaration. Worked for me.

Comment: That can never work. The signature of main method is correct

Comment: This displays an error in the console "Error: Could not find or load main class "